# Using merge in Keras

Tags: python, keras

I am having 3 tensors in keras:

- tensor `a` of shape: `(?,4)`
- tensor `b` of shape: `(?,4)`
- tensor `c` of shape:  `(?, 2, 4)`

where `?` is the batch size. And I want to compute the cosinus similarity/ies between:

- `a` and `b` and,
- `a` and each row of `c` ( for this case 2 rows)

To compute the cos between `a` and `b` the following can be done which is straight forward:

```
from keras.layers import Reshape, merge
cos_a_b = Reshape((1,))(merge([a, b], mode='cos', dot_axes=1))
```

The output is of format `(?,1)` as expected.

But I am unable to find the cos similarities between `a` and `c` (which output should be of the format `(?, 2)`). Using the same `merge` function (`merge([a, c],mode='cos',dot_axes=1)`) I have the error

```
ValueError: Only layers of same output shape can be merged using cos mode. Layer shapes: [(None, 4), (None, 2, 4)]
```

Any idea how to accomplish it?

**Edit**

Following blackplant's answer:

IF I do the following:

```
c_rep = RepeatVector(2)(c)
cos_a_c = merge([a,c_rep],mode='cos', dot_axes=1)
```

I got the following error:

```
Only layers of same output shape can be merged using cos mode. Layer shapes: [(None, Dimension(2), 4), (None, 2, 4)]
```

But if I do the following:

```
cos_a_c = merge([a, RepeatVector(2)(c)],mode='cos', dot_axes=1)
```

the code runs normally but the output is a tensor of shape `(?, 1, 4, 4)`.

With `dot_axes=2` the output is of shape `(?,1, 2, 2)`.

Shouldn't it be `(?,2)`?

Comment: Have you tried `cos_a_c_1= Reshape((1,))(merge([a, c[:,0,:]], mode='cos', dot_axes=1))` and  `cos_a_c_2= Reshape((1,))(merge([a, c[:,1,:]], mode='cos', dot_axes=1))`?

Comment: @DanielMöller thanks for the answer. It doesnt seem its working. It gives the error `TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'` . I guess because `c[:,0,:]` gives back a `Tensor(strided_slice)` and merge cannot be applied to `strided_slices` (?)

Comment: With the approach of repeating the 'a' vector, the dot product becomes a matrix multiplication, which means you will either get a 4x4 or 2x2 matrix. I guess you want to split up your 'c' tensor and apply the dot product to each slice. You can slice the 'c' tensor as described here:  [slicing with Lambda](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/890).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this `merge` approach is well documented. I prefer using documented layers and perform the similarity manually. [Formula taken from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity):

```
import keras.backend as K

def getDivisor(x):

    return K.sqrt(K.sum(K.square(x),axis=-1,keepdims=True))

def similarity(a, b): 

    dividend = K.sum(a*b,axis=-1,keepdims=True)
    return dividend / (getDivisor(a) * getDivisor(b))
```

Now, we should just take some care to make the shapes of `a` and `c` compatible.

```
abSim = Lambda(similarity, output_shape=(1,))([a,b])

aCompatible = Reshape((1,4))(a)
acSim = Lambda(similarity, output_shape=(2,1))([aCompatible,c])
```

---

Maybe just applying the `Reshape((1,4))` to `a` could be enough for using with your `merge` method. But I can't be sure.

Comment: Cool! thanks for the answer. `Reshape` compined with `merge` didnt work. Is there a reason that `Lambda` for `abSim` calculation does not give the expected output shape? It gives a `shape=(?,)` instead of `shape=(?,1)`.

Comment: Hmm, it's because I forgot the `keepdims=True` in the sum method. Actually the `output_shape` passed seems to be necessary only when using theano. In tensorflow it seems to be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [RepeatVector](https://keras.io/layers/core/#repeatvector)? Using this you can repeat the "a " tensor and turn it into a tensor with shape (2,4), at which point you can merge it with c.

```
# Repeat a twice
a_r = RepeatVector(2)(a)
merge([a_r, b], mode='cos', dot_axes=1)
```

EDIT: So it seems that instead of repeating 'a' in order to be able to merge it with 'c' you should instead split up c and apply the dot operation to each slice.

```
# Select first row
c_0 = Lambda(lambda x: x[0,:], output_shape=(4,))(c)
# Compute cos between first row and a
merge([a, c_0], mode='cos', dot_axes=1)
```

Comment: It gives me the following strange error: `Only layers of same output shape can be merged using cos mode. Layer shapes: [(None, Dimension(2), 4), (None, 2, 4)]`

Comment: Can you share the format of 'a' and 'c'? I tried it with the two variables as Input tensors with the shapes you specified and it worked.